# Building dictionary in C# attribute

Tags: c#, attributes

I'm looking to build a dictionary in an attribute.

I know about using `AllowMultiple` in C# attributes, but this causes the attribute to be called and (in my case, because it's a filter) triggered twice.

Essentially, I want this behavior:

```cs
[MyAttribute("someKey", "value1", "value2", "value3")]
[MyAttribute("someOtherKey", "value1", "value2", "value3")]
```

To result in a `Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>` inside `MyAttribute`. However, for obvious reasons this does not work as each line instantiates a whole new `MyAttribute`.

Is there any good way around this? Do attributes support this at all, or do I need to come up with some cheeky way to pass the arguments into one single attribute declaration?

Edit: I should note... This is for an authorization filter. It should work to authorize multiple environments (keys) for multiple potential values. However, I can't use multiple instances of the attribute because then the filter will be triggered multiple times.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to use an attribute?

Comment: This is for an authorization filter. It should work to authorize multiple environments (keys) for multiple potential values. However, I can't use multiple instances of the attribute because then the filter will be triggered multiple times.

Comment: Why is the filter triggered multiple times? (Just to help get a mental model of what's happening.  More context always helps.) Are you doing reflection to find everything that has this attribute, and then stepping through everything on that member's .GetCustomAttributes() method?  If so, couldn't you loop through all instances of the attribute, build your 'dictionary' implemented with AllowMultiple, and then trigger the filter once?

Comment: @SeanSkelly the filter is hit multiple times because that's how filters work. Every time you apply them, it adds a layer of filtering logic to what the request goes through. My attribute is extending `AuthorizeAttribute`. No reflection going on.

Comment: Ah, yes - none of your own reflection; the .NET code is itself doing that.  There is a way to inject complex code into attributes, similar to how System.ComponentModel.TypeConverterAttributes work - you insert a Type (that inherits from TypeConverter) to the constructor of that attribute, and it uses that Type to get the information it needs.  So you'd need a MyAbstractDictionary class that your MyAttribute class expects, define a class MyDictionary : MyAbstractDictionary that overrides a method to return your dictionary, and then MyAttribute is constructed with typeof(MyDictionary).

Comment: Your filter will be hit twice, but each hit executes over a different key and value list. Why is it a problem? Performance?

Comment: @OguzOzgul It's a problem because for some requests one of the filters will authorize successfully but the other one will not.

Comment: Why do you not use the policy system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to insert complex information into an Attribute, using the same pattern as System.ComponentModel.TypeConverterAttribute: by hiding the complexity inside a Type, and using typeof(MyType) as the compile time constant given to the Attribute.

```
public class MyAttributeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public MyAttributeAttribute(Type t) : base()
    {
        if (!typeof(MyAbstractDictionary).IsAssignableFrom(t))
        {
            // ruh roh; wrong type, so bail
            return;
        }
        // could also confirm parameterless constructor exists before using Activator.CreateInstance(Type)

        Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>> dictionary = ((MyAbstractDictionary)Activator.CreateInstance(t)).GetDictionary();
        this.Roles = "Fill Roles by using values from dictionary";
        // fill any other properties from the dictionary
    }
}

public abstract class MyAbstractDictionary
{
    public abstract Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>> GetDictionary();
}

public class MyDictionary : MyAbstractDictionary
{
    public MyDictionary() { } // gotta have a parameterless constructor; add it here in case we actually make another constructor
    public override Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>> GetDictionary()
    {
        Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>> dict = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>();
        // build dictionary however you like
        return dict;
    }
}
```

The abstract class is used so you can create different types that return different dictionaries.

And usage:

```
[MyAttribute(typeof(MyDictionary))]
public class ClassToAttribute { }
```

You can then go on to make class `MyDictionary2` with a different dictionary, and use that as the typeof() for attributing other things.  You can also now use runtime information (!) to build the dictionary, rather than only hard-coded values.

Comment: Thanks, this does functionally solve my problem. Honestly it's a bit of a nightmare with respect to naming / cleanliness though, as if I have different criteria for different controller methods I need new dictionary classes for each. Also, their names should describe their function but that might result in an arduously long class name.